# "First posts" queue should track the user for a bit longer

Tags: feature-request, review, new-users

Currently, the "First posts" queue lists, well, the first posts of a user. Which seems fine, but not ideal, IMO. It is not possible to teach a new user how to use the site by just commenting on just one post of theirs -- it is equally likely that they'll make some other mistake in their second/third posts, and not get that much reviewer attention for those.

I propose we extend the criteria for the "first posts" queue -- it should list the first post**s** of a user, not just the first post (maybe excluding cases where the user gets a good reception for their first post).

Comment: All posts by users below N rep?

Comment: If it goes down that route @DanielFischer N must be >= 12 to account for the double upvotes received from review-monkeys in the queues.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good idea: monitoring only a single post is not enough in many cases, especially if the problem behavior persists. Instead of rigidly tracking the first N posts of a user, I suggest the algorithm also take into account two other factors:

1. The age of the account
2. The average score of the user's questions

This way, if a user has a trend of asking good questions, their posts stop showing up in `/review` sooner. On the other hand, if a person is consistently asking bad questions, they stay on the radar for longer.

Comment: It should also consider the accept rate, as that is an important feature and also a useful metric for a new user.

Comment: @slugster: Not really. A user doesn't even get an accept rate until they have 4 questions over 3 days old with answers on them. A user could get to 10, 15, 20 or more posts before they even get an accept rate. Aside from that, an accept rate isn't always something they can control. If none of the answers are actually helping them, that doesn't necessarily mean we need to review their posts more.

Comment: Well, I sorta already mentioned this in `maybe excluding cases where the user gets a good reception for their first post`, but yeah, I agree :)