# Does a person show up in "first posts" again after their first post is deleted?

Tags: support, review

Slightly silly question, I know. Hear me out.

I recently commented in [another meta thread](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/5243/152073) about how the "first post" review hopper helps new people get their foot in the door with reputation if they're willing to invest the effort.

This got me to thinking: let's say a well-meaning newbie is too fast on the draw, and posts an answer that really should have been a comment. The answer gets deleted per "not a real answer", and then that person posts again. Does the system consider them to be at zero posts again when they make the second post, or was it truly a one time event?

This isn't a statement of opinion, just curiosity. (and I did try searching on `first post` and `zero posts`)

Comment: I have no immediate recollection of specific items, but I swear I've seen someone show up in the First Posts queue again after having their 'real' first post deleted.

Comment: closely related: [First posts queue should track the user for a bit longer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161102), [What are the criteria to be considered a first answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136177)

Comment: @Josh Good catch, I agree it's a duplicate. The wording of this question title might help steer people toward the other question, so at least it might be a marginally useful duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewB: No recrimination intended. I agree, there's plenty of good use for duplicate questions.

Comment: @Josh None taken, it's all good. :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Interesting; that notification came to me instead of AndrewB (Well, I guess it went to him too since it was a reply to his post)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I've wondered what would happen in such a case. Of course, mystery remains: is it because you're first in the comment list, or because Andrew B is the OP and doesn't need to be explicitly `@`-pinged?

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, @AndrewBarber, the rule is that an ambiguous `@`-ping is supposed to match the most _recent_ commenter (Item 4 under "all the details" at [How do comment `@`-replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)), so it must be because Andrew B is the OP.

Comment: We sure do like seeing how deep these rabbit holes go.